# Can't case webusercontrol, namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, webusercontrol

I have this control:

```
public partial class controls_UploadedImageView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
```

And in a static function I have this code:

```
using (var ctl = (controls_UploadedImageView)tmp0.LoadControl("~/controls/UploadedImageView.ascx"))
{
    ctl.RenderControl(h);
}
```

However the cast to `` fails:

> The type or namespace name 'controls_UploadedImageView' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can't work out how to cast the control properly so I can set it's properties before rendering.

### Update

Turns out that as my project is a website project and not a Web Application, it is causing this issue.  A solution is to convert the entire project to a web application but this looks time consuming and fiddly.  Does anyone have any solution that doesn't require me to convert the entire project?

Comment: What namespace does `controls_UploadedImageView` reside in? Have you double-checked you have a `using` directive for that namespace in the caller module? Do both of the code snippets reside in the same assembly?

Comment: Side note: according what you show, cast is not needed. What is there for?

Comment: @Claudio, to *set its properties before rendering*, presumably. The `Control` instance inferred by `var` will not expose these properties.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi It's so I have access to it's properties (specified in question)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm being an idiot, I'm not sure!  Just whatever the default is (global?)

Comment: @Tom Gullen: Obviusly missed that. Sorry

Comment: Seems to be in the `ASP` namespace, but `using ASP` doesn't work in the code creating the control (cannot resolve symbol ASP)

Comment: @Tom, I imagine that casting to `ASP.controls_UploadedImageView` doesn't work either? Your control may reside in another assembly and the caller assembly may lack the appropriate reference. Otherwise, it's hard to say what could be going on, you may want to look for the control in the Class View or the Object Explorer to further analyse the situation.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes you're right, `ASP.controls_UploadedImageView ` doesn't work either, code file can't resolve the `ASP` namespace.

Comment: Is it in App_Code folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have fixed this before by using an interface.

Create an interface in the app_code folder

```
public interface ICustomControl
{
    ... add any extra methods here
}
```

when you declare the class for your user control, include that interface

```
public partial class controls_UploadedImageView : System.Web.UI.UserControl, ICustomControl
```

then use that interface.

```
using (var ctl = (ICustomControl)tmp0.LoadControl("~/controls/UploadedImageView.ascx"))
```

This is all from memory, but hopefully it gets you close to the solution. I'll check my code later if its not helping.

Comment: Working code would be great, not getting too far with this but looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding a namespace to your `.ascx.cs` (may need to update the `.ascx` also). Then add a `using <namespace>;` statement to the class that needs to reference that control.

Ex:

```
namespace MyFancyNamespace
{
    public partial class controls_UploadedImageView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

and...

```
using MyFancyNamespace; //this goes at the top of your class.

using (var ctl = (controls_UploadedImageView)tmp0.LoadControl("~/controls/UploadedImageView.ascx"))
{
    ctl.RenderControl(h);
}
```

Comment: Added into a namespace in both locations, but it cannot find the namespace in my code file generating the control.

Comment: @TomGullen Would you mind posting the relevant code in your question as an update? Also, the control is in the same project as the code that references it?

Comment: Control exists in same solution yes, `ASP` namespace is available everywhere but `App_code` folder for some reason, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @TomGullen Right click your .cs file that references the control, and set the build action to Compile.

Comment: @TomGullen Also, the build action of the .ascx should be Content and the build action of the .ascx.cs should be Compile.

Comment: I don't appear to have a build action menu item when I right click:  http://i.imgur.com/8ODcxD1.jpg

Comment: @TomGullen Sorry, bad description on my part. Right click and then click Properties. that will show a window where you can set the Build Action. Set the build action of all three items as I described in my above comments.

Comment: I'm probably being thick, but right clicking the file has no properties option.  The properties window below the file only has 3 options `Custom Tool`, `File Name` and `Full Path`

Comment: Done a lot more reading on it, it seems like I've created the site as a website project and not web application which is limiting my options here.  Ideally would like a way to access the ASP namespace from app_code folder

Comment: @TomGullen You can convert you project to a web application. I think the easiest way is to just do a new project, manually copy the files into the new project, edit the `@ Page` definitions etc to match the web application style.

Comment: been trying this morning to do it, but looks like it's going to be a huge PITA as it seems to lose tons of references.

Is there any way to get access to the ASP namespace within app_code folder without converting the whole project to a web application?